# Web App with Paypal button PAY not working on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, paypal

I try to add Paypal Button Pay in my web app.
Showcase is https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/pay

This works on Edge, Chrome e Firefox but not on Internet Explorer 11 and older.

I open console with F12 and see:
Promise is undefined (load.js)
Failed to retrieve the 'Promise' property of a null or undefined promise.js reference

How is possible , users don't use Internet Explorer?

Thank a lots
Best regards

Comment: It works for me.... It must be your IE security zone settings or a browser addon. The first step in troubleshooting is to test in noAddons Mode. start>run>iexplore.exe -extoff . To reset your IE security to the default factory settings go Tools>Internet Options>Security tab click "Reset all zones to default". Use the file>properties menu to find out which IE security zone the domain uses... it should be to the Internet zone.

Comment: Last Friday I tried suggest from a link which said the IE security, i tried but same problem...then more late the problem solved by Paypal (i suppose) , after 4 hours I tried and their page with Internet Explorer works. Thanks good bye